# Installing EREG Module for PHP 7.0 on CentOS

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I have a Drupal 8 site running on a PHP 7 stack. At the moment, I am trying to get the site to send mail using the [SMTP module](https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp). Among the requirements for the module is the `ereg` extension.

The trouble is that I cannot seem to find that extension and install it. When I run `php -m` to see the list of loaded extensions, I observe that it is not there. Similarly, when I run `yum list php70*` to list all available extensions, I do not see `ereg` in there.

How can I install this extension and does it even exist?

If it is helpful, I am using the basic EC2 micro instance for this site that runs CentOS.

Comment: The ereg extension (and all ereg_* functions) have been deprecated since PHP 5.3 and removed in PHP 7.

Comment: I don't think that documentation is correct -- there are no calls to any `ereg` functions in the source code for that SMTP module.

Answer (score 2):

This is because in the PHP7 release, they have removed a lot of deprecated methods, the ereg methods having been deprecated since 5.3. These should no longer be used in new code.

[See this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/company/blog/getting-ready-for-php-7/) that has more details.

> The ereg extension (and all ereg_* functions) have been deprecated since PHP 5.3. It should be replaced with the PCRE extension (preg_* functions), which offers many more features.

Comment: I see. Does this mean that the module requires it for other PHP versions and not PHP 7?